# findFirstVisibleItemPosition() of the recyclerview always returns -1

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is the code in which I want to retain recyclerview's scrolled position on orientation change and on activity resume. The problem is in my log, I always get -1. Where am I going wrong?

```
void resetViews() {
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm =  recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    if (lm != null && lm instanceof  LinearLayoutManager) {
        currPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)lm).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        Log.i("saz","curr pos : " + currPosition);
    }
    int count = lm.getChildCount();
    if (currPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && currPosition < count){
        lm.scrollToPosition(currPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your list is not empty ?

Comment: No. It has more than 10 items

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findFirstVisibleItemPosition() it says that there is no visible Item. Do you see some elements when you run your app ?

Comment: Yes I can see the items properly.

Comment: Try with `currPosition = recyclerView.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();`

Comment: This method belongs to LinearLayoutManager, not the RecyclerView class. Do you need any other info regarding the issue? Its actually weird.

Comment: i had a similar problem, my lame workaround was to run ((LinearLayoutManager)lm).findFirstVisibleItemPosition() delayed after 1 second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is extremely simple, since you overloaded the adapter, `LayoutManager` did not have time to build the elements inside of itself, which means that at the moment all the elements are not visible on the screen. If you even try to call `recyclerView.getChildCount()` then you get `0`.

Try something like this:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm = recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
            if (lm != null && lm instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
                currPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager)lm).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                Log.i("saz","curr pos : " + currPosition);
            }
            int count = lm.getChildCount();
            if (currPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && currPosition < count){
                lm.scrollToPosition(currPosition);
            }
        }
    }, 500);
```